# how to make "else" to make desc

Tags: php, mysql

I am building a table that location in "php my admin" and I did that in the first click on one of the "th" its asc and now Im trying to make desc in the second click.. any ideas?

Amm.. a lot I dont remember sorry...

```
if($order == '' ) {

    $order= id;

}

$homework6 = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM homework6 WHERE manufacturer_hebrew LIKE '%$x%' order by $order asc"); 
$rows = $homework6->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC); 



echo '<div >';
echo '<table border= "1" >';
echo '<th colspan="1">'. '<a href="?order=id">x</a>' .'</th>';
echo '<th colspan="1">'. '<a href="?order=manufacturer_hebrew">x</a>' .'</th>';
echo '<th colspan="1">'. '<a href="?order=manufacturer_english">x</a>' .'</th>';
echo '<th colspan="1">'. '<a href="?order=Models_number">x</a>' .'</th>';
echo '<th colspan="1">'. '<a href="?order=made_in">x</a>' .'</th>';
foreach ($rows as $paz) 
{  if ($paz['Models_number'] < 2 )  {
    $color = "bg-danger";
}
elseif ($paz['Models_number'] < 10){
    $color = "bg-warning";
}   
 elseif ($paz['Models_number'] < 15){
    $color = "bg-success";
}

else {$color = "bg-primary";} 
echo '<tr class='.$color.'>';
echo '<td >' .$paz['id']. '</td>';
echo '<td>' .$paz['manufacturer_hebrew']. '</td>';
echo '<td>' .$paz['manufacturer_english']. '</td>';    
echo '<td>' .$paz['Models_number']. '</td>';
echo '<td >' .$paz['made_in']. '</td>';
echo '</tr>';
        }
echo '</table>';
echo '</div>';
```

now just the 'asc' works.

Comment: Mind the SQL injections..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach should be something like this: you should **explicitly** define which sort order will be used when user clicks the link. This can be done for example like this:

```
$currentSort = isset($_GET['sort']) ? $_GET['sort'] : 'asc';
$newSort = $currentSort === 'asc' ? 'desc' : 'asc';
```

Next you use `$currentSort` in your query, and `$newSort` is passed to link:

```
$homework6 = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM homework6 WHERE manufacturer_hebrew LIKE '%$x%' order by $order $currentSort"); 

echo '<th colspan="1">'. '<a href="?order=id&sort=' . $newSort .'">x</a>'.'</th>';
```

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but I would suggest against putting `$_GET['sort']` directly into the query. I'd make it explicit: `$currentSort = isset($_GET['sort']) && $_GET['sort'] === 'desc' ? 'desc' : 'asc';` just to avoid the risk of SQL injection via that parameter. Although the same (risk of SQL injection) also applies to the already existing variables `$x` and `$order`, wherever they came from.

Comment: Not the downvoter but this code still has a Cross site scripting injection vurnablitity aswell not only the SQL injection which @rickdenhaan had mentioned..

Comment: I agree with remarks about security, but I just presented an approach to start from, not a fully described example.

Answer (score 0):

I think, It would be something like this: (not tested)

```
if ($order == '') {
    $order = id;
}

$sort = strpos($order, '-') ? 'desc' : 'asc';
$orderBy = str_replace('-', '', $order);

$homework6 = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM homework6 WHERE manufacturer_hebrew LIKE '%$x%' order by $orderBy $sort");
$rows = $homework6->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

$headColumns = [
    ['sort' => 'id', 'name' => 'x'],
    ['sort' => 'manufacturer_hebrew', 'name' => 'x'],
    ['sort' => 'manufacturer_english', 'name' => 'x'],
    ['sort' => 'Models_number', 'name' => 'x'],
    ['sort' => 'made_in', 'name' => 'x'],
];

echo '<div >';
echo '<table border= "1" >';

foreach ($headColumns as $headColumn) {
    $direction = strpos($order, $headColumn['sort']) && strpos($order, '-') === false ? '-' : '';
    echo '<th colspan="1"><a href="?order='.$direction.$headColumn['sort'].'">'.$headColumn['name'].'</a></th>';
}

foreach ($rows as $paz) {
...
```